# Combining values with text in python function

Tags: python, variables

I have a python script that scrapes a webpage and downloads the mp3s found on it.

I am trying to name the files using elements that I have successfully captured in a separate function.

I am having trouble naming the downloaded files, this is what I have so far:

```
def make_safe_filename(text: str) -> str:
    """convert forbidden chars to underscores"""
    return ''.join(c if (c.isalnum() or c.isspace()) else '_' for c in text).strip('_ ')

filename = make_safe_filename(a['artist'] + a['title'] + a['date'] + a['article_url'])
```

I am trying to save the file name as "Artist - Title - Date - Article_url" however I am struggling to do this. At the moment the variables are all mashed together without spaces, eg. ArtistTitleDateArticle_url.mp3

I've tried

```
filename = make_safe_filename(a['artist'] + "-" + a['title'] + "-" + a['date'] + "-" + 
a['article_url'])
```

but this throws up errors.

Can anyone shed some light on where I am going wrong? I know it's something to do with combining variables but I am stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but this throws up errors." - could you be more specific about what errors are being thrown (EG TypeError, ValueError etc)? This might make it easier to answer the question. Also, could you give an example of one of the inputs to `make_safe_filename` that you have tried, so that other can recreate the same error? This might make it easier to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: You should join the parts within the function, otherwise you will just replace the `-` with `_`.

Comment: @tobias_k how do I achieve this? You are right, as it seems to be 'working' now, though replacing the - with _. I think I might have to rewrite the make_safe_filename function?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your `a` is a dictionary? Maybe you could clarify this in your question? Also what do you typically have in `a['article_url']`? Could you also post the traceback?

This is my attempt (note: no changes to the function):

```
def make_safe_filename(text: str) -> str:
    """convert forbidden chars to underscores"""
    return ''.join(c if (c.isalnum() or c.isspace()) else '_' for c in text).strip('_ ')

a = {
    'artist': 'Metallica',
    'title': 'Nothing Else Matters',
    'date': '1991',
    'article_url': 'unknown',
    }

filename = make_safe_filename(a['artist'] + '-' + a['title'] + '-' + a['date'] + '-' + a['article_url'])
print(filename)
```

Which produced the following output:

```
Metallica_Nothing Else Matters_1991_unknown
```

Comment: Thanks. 'articles' is indeed a dictionary, of which a is used to pull out individual items. 'articlue-url' typicall has a value like XYZ-123

Answer (score 1):

You code *should* actually work, but if you add the `-` before passing the joined string to the function, it will just replace those with `_` as well. Instead, you could pass the individual fields and then `join` those in the function, after replacing the "illegal" characters for each field individually. Also, you could regular expressions and `re.sub` for the actual replacing:

```
 import re
 def safe_filename(*fields):
    return " - ".join(re.sub("[^\w\s]", "_", s) for s in fields)

>>> safe_filename("Art!st", "S()ng", "§$%")
'Art_st - S__ng - ___'
```

Of course, if your `a` is a dictionary and you always want the same fields from that dict (artist, title, etc.) you could also just pass the dict itself and extract the fields within the function.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your last point? a is a dictionary as such         articles.append({
            'artist': artist,
            'date': date,
            'title': title,
            'mp3_url': mp3_url,
            'article_url': article_url,

Comment: @LearningPython I just meant that instead of passing the four fields (artist, title, date, url) individually or as a list, you could also pass the `a` dict itself and then extract the relevant fields within the function. If you have to call the function multiple times, and each time pass those values from a dictionary, than this might be simpler. If not, just keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, the best solution is probably to use regex, but I'm too lazy to learn that, so I wrote a `replaceAll` function:

```
def replaceAll(string, characters, replacement):
    s = string
    for i in characters:
        s = s.replace(i, replacement)
    return s
```

and then I used it to make a usable filename:

```
fName = replaceAll(name, '*<>?|"/\\.,\':', "")
```

in your case it would be:

```
filename = replaceAll(a['artist'] + a['title'] + a['date'] + a['article_url'], '*<>?|"/\\.,\':', "-")
```